# Why does this python list need so much more memory?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, one-hot-encoding

I want to create a list of numpy arrays in python. The arrays are mostly zeroes, with few flags set to one.

When running the following code, I run into memory issues. The code requires ~double the memory that I expect it to use.

Python loop to fill the list:

```
vectorized_data = []
os.system("free -m")
for dat in data: #data has length 200000
    one_hot_vector = np.zeros(6000)
    for d in dat:
        one_hot_vector[d] = 1
    vectorized_data.append(one_hot_vector)
os.system("free -m") ##memory usage goes up by ~7.5GB
```

Amount of memory I expect this code to use (vector dimension: 6000, #samples: 200000, numpy float bytes: 4):

```
(6000 * 200000 * 4) /(2**30.0) ~= 4.47 GB
```

Amount of memory actually used:

```
~7.5 GB
```

Is there any more memory-efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: Both, `data`, and `vectorized_data` are being held in memory, if i understand it correctly.

Comment: @jmunsch that's correct.

Comment: A vector containing only zeros and ones has much better possible representations than an array of 4-byte floats...

Comment: How big is `data`? `data[:200000]` creates another copy of the first `200000` items in `data`.

Comment: @AChampion that was just to make the size of data obvious, updated how the code actually looks like

Comment: `np.zeros(6000).dtype == dtype('float64')` and `np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize == 8` (at least on my computer) - that could explain the size difference you are multiplying by the wrong number they are 8 bytes not 4 bytes each. Perhaps you need `np.zeros(6000, np.float32)` (or `np.int32`).

Comment: @jasonharper Shouldn't the array actually  only store the values that are non-zero by default? According to the numpy docs "subok : bool, optional.
If True, then the newly created array will use the sub-class type of ‘a’, otherwise it will be a base-class array. Defaults to True."

Comment: An array has to store all of its values, not just the ones you changed.  I have no idea what that quote from the docs has to do with this.

Comment: Is `data` a list or an array?  If an array `data[:20000]` does not make a copy.

Comment: This doesn't address the memory issue, but does `one_hot_vector[dat] = 1` work?  In other words, do you really need to iterate on `d in dat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could use a generator and row/column id something like:

```
def yield_row(data):
  for r_id, dat in enumerate(data):
      tmp = np.zeros(6000)
      for d in dat:
          tmp[d] = 1
      yield r_id, tmp

for r_id, tmp in yield_row(data):
  if is_hot_vector(tmp):
    do_stuff()
```

This approach has the downside of only having access to the row/column ids and the current tmp row, however it reduces the amount of memory needed to `data` plus one row.

Another approach might be to add only the row id to a list instead of the entire row, just index the row, and if needed add the translation/transform.